# Why ++variable isn't treated as lvalue in C?

Tags: c, lvalue

Consider the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 0;
    printf("%d\n", ++a += 1);
}
```

`++` has precedence over `+=` so it should be evaluated first. So we have `a` on the left and `1` on the right. Now based on my understanding `++a` should result in `a` (only changes its value) which is lvalue so why this statement gives the following error:

```
lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Comment: Even if it was an lvalue, it would result in undefined behavior. Anyway, `++a` is not resulting in  `a`, it is resulting in a *value* of `a`. And you can't assign stuff to values.

Comment: The `++` operator is unusual in that it operates on (modifies) its operand.  But that doesn't mean it yields an lvalue.  It yields an rvalue, just like most other operators.  (I believe the only operator that yields an lvalue is unary `*`, and its syntactic sugar `[]`.)

Comment: What's the use case where `a += 2` wouldn't be usable?

Comment: @BoP It's not particularly useful I was just curious about how the language works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prefix increment operator `++` results in the incremented value of its operand, however it is not an lvalue.  Section 6.5.3.1p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf): describes the semantics as follows:

> The value of the operand of the prefix `++` operator is incremented.
> The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation. The
> expression `++E` is equivalent to `(E+=1)`. See the discussions of
> additive operators and compound assignment for information on
> constraints, types, side effects, and conversions and the effects of
> operations on pointers.

Then section 6.5.16.2p3 regarding compound assignment operators states:

> A compound assignment of the form `E1 op = E2` is equivalent to the
> simple assignment expression `E1 = E1 op (E2)`, except that the lvalue
> `E1` is evaluated only once, and with respect to an
> indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of a compound
> assignment is a single evaluation.

And 6.5.16p3 regarding the assignment operator further states:

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the
> left operand. **An assignment expression has the value of the left
> operand after the assignment, but is not an lvalue.**

So it is explicitly not allowed.  Even if it was, an expression such as `++a += 1` would cause `a` to be modified more than once without an intervening sequence point which would trigger undefined behavior.

This is one of those place where C and C++ differ.  C++ does in fact allow the result of the `=` operator, and by extension compound assingment and prefix `++`/`--`, to be an lvalue.